# Coveo SAP Connector: How to Configure Multiple Sources to Index Different Documents?

Tags: json, search, configuration, coveo

I have successfully configured a Coveo SAP connector to index documents using a specific JSON configuration (mentioned below).

The issue I am trying to solve is that I want to create another source with a similar configuration to index different documents (eg. have another copy). The goal is to manage distinct content for each source, but the issue is that, whether I run source 1 or source 2 they will index the same documents.

Below is a snippet of my current source JSON configuration used in 2 sources:

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "url": "https://...",
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Application-Interface-Key": "..."
      },
      "paging": {
        "pageSize": 100,
        "offsetStart": 0,
        "offsetType": "item",
        "nextPageKey": "__next",
        "parameters": {
          "limit": "$top",
          "offset": "$skip"
        }
      },
      "endpoints": [
        {
          "path": "/Product/Products",
          "method": "GET",
          "queryParameters": {
            "$filter": "catalogVersion/integrationKey eq 'Online%7CpowertoolsProductCatalog' and approvalStatus/code eq 'approved'",
            "$expand": "supercategories,thumbnails,picture,thumbnail,unit,catalogVersion/catalog,europe1Prices,europe1Prices/currency,approvalStatus,localizedAttributes"
          },
          "itemPath": "d.results",
          "itemType": "product",
          "uri": "https://.../en/USD/%[code]",
          "clickableUri": "https://.../en/USD/%[code]",
          "metadata": {
            "objecttype": "Product",
            "ec_brand": "%[manufacturerName]",
            "systitle": "%[name]",
            "title": "%[name]",
            "ec_name": "%[localizedAttributes.results[*].name]",
            "ec_code": "%[code]",
            "ec_description": "%[description]",
            "ec_price": "%[europe1Prices.results[0].price]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have already created two sources, but I am unsure about how to make them unique so that they don't index the same documents. I'm seeking advice on what parameters or configurations can be adjusted to ensure that each source indexes its own set of documents.

Any suggestions or insights into Coveo's configuration options for achieving this separation of content in multiple sources would be greatly appreciated.